# Properties of modified Ricci-flat condition

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, mathematical-physics

Motivated by physics$^\dagger$, I am interested in manifolds which solve,

$$R_{ab} = -\alpha R_{acde} R^{cde}_b$$

where $\alpha >0$ and we have the usual Riemann and Ricci tensors. I know that for $R_{ab} = 0$ the fact the manifold is Ricci flat has implications on for example, its holonomy.

Are solutions to the above constraint known or studied in the mathematical literature?

---

$\dagger$ These are the Einstein equations with first order modifications by string theory.